# Circumventing the default scoping: Assign a variable inside a function

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, scoping, assignment

I'm currently trying very hard to assign a variable inside a function.
Therefore I'm using a function like this, which should reassign a predefined variable.

```
assign[a_] := (HoldForm@a = 2)
a=1;
assign[a]
```

The problem is that Mathematica uses the value of "a" instead of its name.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You should investigate attributes. Specifically, the ones whose names start with `Hold`. Alternatively you could perhaps use `Unevaluated`. But, trying to do the assignment as `HoldForm[a] = whatever` is not valid since `HoldForm` is `Protected`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks--I had been looking for a duplicate but didn't succeed in finding it. Actually, I was looking for a different one, but your suggestion is a good match.

Comment: @OleksandrR. No problem. This seems to be a common question, you are right - there were at least several related discussions here and on SO - and on MathGroup before that.

Answer (score 2):

As Oleksandr R. commented, you can do this by setting the appropriate attributes, e.g.

```
SetAttributes[assign, HoldFirst];

assign[z_] := z = 2

a = 1;
assign[a]
assign[b]

{a, b}

(* {2,2} *)
```

However, there's a reason for scoping rules and constructs, I'd think long and hard before 'circumventing' them, whatever that may mean in your case.